# How to solve this partial derivative equation ?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, neural-networks

Using the following model

$$
H_\theta(X)=\theta^TX 
$$
Where $\theta $ is a vector of parameters.

The cost function is, 
$$
J(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=0}^{m}(h_\theta(X^i)-y^i)^2
$$
Now given 
$$
\dfrac{\delta J(\theta)}{\delta\theta}
$$

Show that

$$
\theta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$

Can anyone give me any solution of it?

Comment: You'll find this covered in Andrew Ng's excellent notes here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the standard solution to a [linear least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)), the solution to the [normal equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html).

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$, $\Theta\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. The energy is
$$
J(\Theta) = \frac{1}{2m}||X\Theta - y||_2^2=\frac{1}{2m}\left[ \Theta^TX^TX\Theta - 2y^TX\Theta + y^Ty \right]
$$
Then the first variation is
$$
\frac{\delta J}{\delta \Theta} = \frac{1}{2m}
\left[
\frac{\delta}{\delta \Theta}(\Theta^TX^TX\Theta) - 2 \frac{\delta}{\delta \Theta}(y^TX\Theta)
\right]
$$
Let's compute these inner vector derivatives using components:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_j}(y^TX\Theta) 
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_j}\sum_i \sum_k y_iX_{ik}\Theta_k=\sum_i y_iX_{ij}\\\therefore \frac{\delta}{\delta \Theta}(y^TX\Theta) &= y^TX\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_j}(\Theta^TX^TX\Theta) 
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_j}\sum_k\left[ \sum_i X_{ki}\Theta_i \right]^2\\
&= \sum_k 2\left[ \sum_i X_{ki}\Theta_i \right] X_{kj}\\
&=2\sum_k [X\Theta]_k X_{kj}\\
&= 2(X\Theta)^TX^j\\
\therefore \frac{\delta}{\delta \Theta}(\Theta^TX^TX\Theta) &= 2(X\Theta)^TX
\end{align}
Now equate the variation to zero:
$$
\frac{\delta J}{\delta \Theta}
=\frac{1}{2m}
\left[
2(X\Theta)^TX - 2 y^TX
\right]
=0
$$
Now it's pretty trivial to solve the equation:
$$
\Theta^TX^TX=y^TX
$$
$$
X^TX\Theta = X^Ty
$$
$$
\Theta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$